# Server 2008 VPS providers

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, vps

I am looking for an affordable and reliable VPS solution serving Windows Server 2008.
 Use case is to run a Continuous Integration build Server for an asp.net mvc site project.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm investigating VPS solutions right now and compiled a list along with pricing. For Server 2008 I would not recommend anything below 1 GB of RAM. Please note that some items below indicate Server 2003 but also have the 2008 option available.

> http://vpsland.com/xlwin.html
>   $80 - 1024MB RAM, 40 GB disk, 1000 GB bandwidth, 2 IPs, Server 2003 Enterprise
>
> http://liquidweb.com
>   $90 - 1024 MB RAM, 100 GB disk, 700 GB bandwidth, 4 IPs (additional $0.5 each), Server 2003
>
> http://www.solarvps.com/products-win.php (Virtuozzo)
>   $73.50 - 1056 MB RAM, 50 GB disk, 800 GB bandwidth, 5 IPs (additional $1 each), Server 2003 MANAGED
>   $73.50 - 1184 MB RAM, 60 GB disk, 600 GB bandwidth, 5 IPs (additional $1 each), Server 2003 MANAGED
>   $40 - 768 MB RAM, 50 GB disk, 600 GB bandwidth, 5 IPs (additional $1 each), Server 2003 UNMANAGED
>
> http://kickassvps.com/services/windows_2008.php (Virtuozzo)
>   $90 - 1920MB RAM, 40 GB disk, 400 GB bandwidth, 2 IPs, Server 2008 Enterprise 64-bit
>
> http://fullcontrol.net/ (Hyper-V)
>   $79 - 1GB RAM, 40 GB disk, 1000 GB bandwidth, 2 IPs, Server 2008 Standard 32-bit (+$10 for x64)
>   $89 - 1GB RAM, 40 GB disk, 1000 GB bandwidth, 8 IPs, Server 2008 Standard 32-bit (+$10 for x64)
>
> https://www.webspacedepot.com/vps_plans_windows.php (Hyper-V)
>   $26.93 - 1024MB RAM, 90 GB disk, 1000GB bandwidth, 2 IPs, Server 2003/2008, 2 CPU cores
>   $36.93 - 1536MB RAM, 130 GB disk, 1100GB bandwidth, 2 IPs, Server 2003/2008, 2 CPU cores
>   $50.93 - 2048MB RAM, 200 GB disk, 1200GB bandwidth, 5 IPs, Server 2003/2008, 3 CPU cores
>
> http://www.servebyte.com/windows.html (xen)
>   $50 - 1GB RAM, 80 GB disk, 480GB bandwidth, 3 IPs, Server 2003, 2.0 GHz cpu cycles
>   $90 - 2GB RAM, 160 GB disk, 1024GB bandwidth, 4 IPs, Server 2003, 2.5 GHz cpu cycles

Comment: @smartins i'm researching these options now too.  which did you go with in the end and any findings?

Comment: For what it's worth, I've had a Server 2008 VPS from KickAss VPS for about 3 months now and I am spending today looking for other options.  They don't let you install your own OS updates, IIS is SUPER flaky, and Virtuozzo goes down fairly regularly.  My VPS hangs consistently and I have to forcibly reboot it.

Comment: @Kyel Noland what was the final verdict? which one did you go for in the end?

Comment: and the same question to @smartins.

Comment: Just to add to the list: [contabo](http://contabo.com/) for 15 euros/month you get windows 2012 VPS with 3.2 Ghz core, 4Gb rams, 200 Gb disk, 100 Mbit/sec channel and unlimited traffic. I'm a happy customer.

Answer (score 2):

1. The most affordable in the realm of Hyper-V (more robust solution than Virtuozzo):
   [WebSpaceDepot](https://www.webspacedepot.com/vps_plans_windows.php)
2. Also very affordable VPS based on Parallels Virtuozzo technology with respected provider:
   [KickAss VPS](http://www.kickassvps.com/services/windows_vps/plans.php)

Answer (score 0):

[myhosting.com](http://myhosting.com) offers 2 Windows Server 2008 Hyper-V VPS plans. Quick setup and very stable so far.
http://myhosting.com/virtual-server-hosting/windows-plans.aspx

- $39.95 - 512MB, 25GB
- $69.95 - 1GB, 50GB